# How to send byte[] as document to the Client?

Tags: c#, .net, byte, document

I have, in a WebForm (on .NET 3.5) a `byte[]`, which "represent" a PDF file.

Well, I'd like to send it to the client, during a request (postback) from this page.

How can I do it? Tried searching, but I find only tutorial of byte[] from client to server.

Comment: What makes you think the networking classes in .Net know about servers vs clients?

Comment: @DanielKelley: That comment doesn't make a lot of sense, don't you think? There is quite a big difference between Request and Response. For starters: Those are different classes.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Afraid I don't get your comment. From the networks perspective there is a sender and a receiver. What difference does it make if the server or client is sending or receiving?

Comment: You want the client to see the pdf in the browser ? or download it ?

Comment: @DanielKelley: The point is that you normally don't work with the low level networks API, but with high level APIs.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I still don't get your point. If the OP has seen an article that says how to send data from a "client" to a "server" why would the code be any different sending in the opposite direction? Can you point me to a "client sender" class or a "server receiver" class?

Comment: @DanielKelley: A simple example: If you have an ASP.NET Web API and you want to send a `byte[]` to the server (as in web server), you would create completely different code as if you want to return a `byte[]` from the web server to the client. The answer by Mike illustrates this point quite nicely. Especially in the World Wide Web, server and client aren't interchangable. The Web Server is always the one accepting the connection, the Client is always the one initiating the connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way, but you might have to clear the Response first to remove all the other page controls etc.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("test.pdf");

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");
    Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
    Response.Flush();

    Response.End();
}
```

I usually create an IHttpHandler or WCF REST service to serve up files though.

Comment: Is `Response.Flush()` actually necessary there?

Comment: Can you show an example with IHttpHandler? Would be nice, never use them!

Comment: No, looks like `Response.End()` does call `Flush()` internally.

Comment: Example of an [IHttpHandler](http://geekswithblogs.net/hmloo/archive/2012/03/07/how-to-download-files-using-a-generic-handler.aspx). I would not recommend passing the file name like they do in that example, rather pass an file id or something and remember to authenticate access to the resource.

Comment: Also, this "download" the document! If I'd like to open it?

Comment: Leave this line out if you want the file to open directly: `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");`